# How to format birt date report parameter?

Tags: birt

By default if the input parameter to BIRT report is of type Date, it takes `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Can we change to something else e.g. may be `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

Comment: Troubleshooting:            `//Internet Explorer: Tools->Internet Options-> Languages...
            //Control Panel: Regional and language options->Standards and formats, Location.
            // RDL file:   <Language>es-ES</Language>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the input format for a date parameter. Click on "Change..." select Format as "Custom" and you can enter a valid format code as you like.

If you want to enter a default Date you still have to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` Format, this cannot be changed ( where I used `new Date()` in the Picture), but the output format will still be your entered format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the format Date Time section in the Birt designer and choose the right locale and formatting for the date.

I have done it in Birt 3.7 and works fine

Answer (score -1):

There can be many way to do that but the easy one is you can do this in SQL Query itself.

If you are using DB2 you may try

VARCHAR_FORMAT("Your Column Mapping Name",'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS dataSetName.

**But this will change its Data type to String**

Try if this make any seance.

Comment: This only works for data you selected from an SQL Data Source, but the question was about Input Parameters. This is a totally different section of the report.